# Go to line in less command is not working if using "+Gg" at the same time

Tags: less

I want to go to line 100 directly when opening a file, but I use `-M` and `+Gg` at the same time to show verbose detail in status bar.

- `-M` is for the file name and line number of the current screen
- `+Gg` will give you the information of the whole line number of the current file and the percentage of the current screen.

So, I want to use:

```
less -M +Gg +100 file
```

to go to line 100 and keep all the info in the status bar I want, but the `+100` is not working.

I know `+Gg` means that go to the end of the file and then go to the beginning , but I really like to keep the info `+Gg` provide in the status line.

So, any advice?

Comment: `less -M +100 file` is giving `file lines 100-129/3519 4%` here. What more gives `+Gg`?

Comment: @FloHimself `less -M +100 file` won't give `/3519 4%` unless you reach the end of the file, `+Gg` give you that from the start.

Comment: Here it gives that info with just `-M +100` right from the start...

Comment: NOTICE: Crossposted to http://superuser.com/questions/906131/go-line-in-less-command-is-not-working-if-using-gg-at-the-same-time -- VERY BAD

Comment: @FloHimself Not for me, did you make a alias or configuration in your .bashrc? BTW, `less v471, Fedora 21`

Comment: No alias. `less 418, OSX Yosemite`, `less 458, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS` and `less 444, Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)`

Comment: @FloHimself I tried to compile v458 from the source code and using just `./less -M +100 file`, still no `/3519 4%`. but now even if I add `+Gg`, it won't show the `/3519 4%`.

Comment: `less -M file` does give `/number-of-lines percent%` you do not have to navigate to end first. However `cat file | less -M` does not. Are you using a pipe? Or is it configured to use one?

Comment: @richard No pipe, all i'm using is `$ less -M +100 file` or `/usr/bin/less -M +100 file` in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`less -M +G100g`

The manual `+<linenumber>` is a special case for `+<linenumber>g` (probably does not work in all contexts).